# How to pass javascript value in Razor syntax(as a parameter value)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, syntax, jqgrid

i am using jquery grid in MVC 3 .as a formatter option i am using following code as a script segment.

```
function viewformateadorLink(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
             return "<a href=../xxx/yyy/Edit/" + rowObject[0] + ">" + cellvalue + "</a>";   
         }
```

but i don't want to use href here .better option i have found is as follows:

```
func....(){
   var url = '@Html.ActionLink( "_name_", "Edit", new { id = "_id_" })';
           url = url.replace(/_name_/, cellvalue);
           url = url.replace(/_id_/, rowObject[0]);
           return url;    
   }
```

are there any simple way exist for passing parameter?

Comment: Your code seems fine. What issues are you encountering?

Comment: That's very similar, if not an improvement to how I've been doing the same thing.  I like your sort of token replacement idea.  I'd previously used @ViewBag.RedirectUrl = @Html.ActionUrl(arg, arg) to generate a URL and then used onclick="window.location.href='@ViewBag.RedirectUrl'" in my HTML control to redirect.  Feels kinda dirty, I'd also be interested in any cleaner ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value you want to pass to the link is in a JavaScript variable and you don't want to use href, then I'm afraid you can't go further than you already have gone and this is why:

The JavaScript code is ALWAYS executed after the server-side code.

I imagine you would like to do something like:

```
@Html.ActionLink( "_name_", "Edit", new { id = *JAVASCRIPT VARIABLE* })
```

but due to the reason I mentioned above, such thing is impossible.

I would suggest you stick to any of the other methods you used in your question.